# Question about converse of Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I am working on the following and seemingly need several nudges:

Let $I$ be some interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f: I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if for all
$a, b \in I$ with $a < b$ and every $x$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there is a $t \in [a, b]$ such that $f(t) = x$. (Here between means in $[f(a), f(b)]$ if $f(a) \leq f(b)$ or in $[f(b), f(a)]$ is $f(b) < f(a)$.)

**My thoughts so far**: For the forward direction, fix $a$ and $b$ in $I$ and without loss of generality, $a<b$. By the intermediate value theorem, we are done.

**A Concern:** However, the backward direction seems like a converse to the intermediate value theorem, which I thought was false. What is the distinction here that allows this to be true?

**More thoughts:** Finally, if $f$ is a continuous bijection between intervals, I am asked whether $f$ is strictly increasing (or decreasing) and whether $f^{-1}$ is continuous. I think $f$ is either strictly increasing or decreasing and that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

For the former, take two points in the interval $I$ as before and since $f$ is bijective, their images are not equal under $f$. Then, there are two cases: $a<b$, either $f(a)<f(b)$ or $f(a)>f(b)$. I think I will have to use the first part somehow to conclude strictly increasing or decreasing for each case.

Comment: It's false. $f(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x}$ with $f(0) = 0$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: So, does it matter that this hypothesis is for *all* $a,b\in I$? That seems like a stronger condition to me than IVT.

Comment: Well, no, since the function I've given satisfies your condition and yet is not continuous.

Comment: You need hypotheses on $f$. For example, if $f$ is a function of bounded variation, then $f$ is continuous iff it has the intermediate value property.